# Functional programming in Python: Longest substring

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am reading and hearing people talking about functional programming and I am trying to wrap my head around it and understand if it is applicable to me. 
I am a **sysadmin** (please, talk slowly) who writes lots of Python code.

Unfortunately most examples of FP I find are using esoteric languages and solving complex math problems.

If anyone has a few minutes to spare, would you mind show me how you would solve this using Python + FP, please? It's a much more realistic problem for me.

This is my "regular" approach:

```
def long(text: str) -> int:
    visited = []
    longest, count = 0, 0
    for i in text:
        if i not in visited:
            count += 1
            if longest < count:
                longest = count
            visited.append(i)
        else:
            count = 1
            visited = [i]
    return longest
```

And the test case:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(('input', 'output'), [("", 0), ('abc', 3), ('a', 1), ('abcabc', 3),
                        ('abcabcd', 4), ('abcab', 3), ('abcabcdabcdeab', 5), ('aaaa', 1),
                        (string.ascii_lowercase, 26)])
def test_long(input, output):
    x = long.long(input)
    assert x == output
```

Comment: You might just want [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks) (or are you after the longest *repeated* substring - that's a whole different kettle of fish :p)

Comment: Have a read of [this](https://stackabuse.com/functional-programming-in-python/). It explains the fundementals of FP, however Python isn't a functional language, I'd recommend having a look at Haskell or Prolog

Comment: Functional programming is basically limiting yourself to functions that only operate on the input (without modifying the input) and returning an output for the caller to use. Your code is *already* functional from that perspective. Perhaps you are looking for additional purety and only use immutable objects for your locals as well? Then just use `visited = frozenset()`, and use `visited = visited | frozenset((char,))` to create a new set each time with a character added (using a set instead of a list would otherwise already be a great idea here).

Comment: I see that someone built a full functional toolset from the Haskell version of the closely related problem of finding the longest common substring between two strings, over on RosettaStone, to give you a [pure functional version using generic functions](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_Common_Substring#Functional).